# Azure DevOps Build Submodule

Tags: github, ssh, azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-pipelines

I have a private bitbucket repo that is connected to the Azure DevOps Build Pipeline. 
The private repo has a submodule connected to a public Github repo.

Both repositories are accessed via SSH.

I have ticked the clone submodules box in DevOps.

How do I provide an SSH key to Azure DevOps so it will clone the submodule?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution for this was not to change to https, or setup a self hosted agent.

There is a step available called Load an SSH key.

I created a new ssh key on github, added the Load SSH Key step to the VSTS tasks.

It runs before the Checkout task (despite appearing in the queue afterwards) and loads the required ssh key on the agent

Comment: Hahaha! Just came across this in my travels with Azure Devops xD

Answer (score 1):

It's unnecessary to provider SSH Key to Azure DevOps, you just need to **modify the `.gitmodules` file** in the private bitbucket repo **to specify the submodule github repo URL with HTTP protocol**.

Such as modify the `.gitmodules` file as:

```
[submodule "myrepo"]
    path = myrepo
    url = https://github.com/username/myrepo.git
```

---

Now, when you queue the build again, it will download the submodule repo successful in Get sources (checkout) step.

While for the reason why it mainly build failed at Get sources step, it's caused the build agent does not have the SSH key which matches in Github, when get the soubmodule sources. So if you do not want to modify `.gitmodules` file with HTTP protocol, you should to queue the build which the [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) which contains the ssk public key you specified in GitHub.

Detail steps to setup a self-hosted agent as below:

1. Create and copy a PAT in the page https://account.visualstudio.com/_usersSettings/tokens for later use. If you already have PAT, then skip this step.
2. Download agent

   In Agent pools page (https://account.visualstudio.com/_settings/agentpools) -> download agent to the local machine where GitHub repo SSH locates -> unzip in a directory.

   [image]
3. Setup self-hosted agent

   In the unzipped directory -> open PowerShell as Administrator -> execute `./config.cmd` -> enter URL, PAT, agent pool (such as Default agent pool) etc as it hints.

   After configuration -> if the agent is offline line -> execute `./run.cmd` in the PowerShell window to make sure the agent state is Online.

   [image]

Now you can queue build with your self-hosted agent.

Comment: The problem with updating the .gitmodules to use https is that I then need to use https to communicate with the github repo, which if I want to push changes to that repo means putting a user name and password into the gitmodules / or sourcetree. Ssh resolves this issue, and is the preferred way of accessing git repositories. I would like to be able to add the SSH key to the build agent, but I don't understand how I would do that with the self hosted agent from the link provided?

Comment: @DeanMarcussen I updated my answer detail detail steps to setup a self-hosted agent, you can have a try. Besides, using http protocol, you can also integrate the username and password in the repo URL (`https://username:password@github.com/myrepo.git`), so that it won't be interrupted with the communication window.

Comment: This didn't really sound like a solution for the question - going to http and including user names and passwords inside a git repo seems a very backward step. Nor do I want to run a self hosted agent - again defeats the purpose of VSTS. I did however discover a step that would load an ssh agent so that resolves it for me

Comment: @DeanMarcussen since your problem has been solved, you can mark your own answer. And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions.